# THREE.PointsMaterial corruption?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a .png texture into a THREE.js PointsMaterial, works fine however every so often the texture renders either totally or partly corrupted, not every time but perhaps 40% of the time or so.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
new_texture = textureLoader.load("smiley.png");

new_material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 10,
  map: new_texture,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthTest: false,
  transparent: true,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});

//add some points to a geometry object etc...

scene.add(new THREE.Points(sceneGeometry, new_material));
```

I cant for the life of me work out how to fix it / stop it from happening, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "corrupted". Add a screenshot. I will take a guess though and say it may have something to do with the transparency and that you have `depthTest: false` and `transparent:true`. Chances are you would want to have depthTest set to true if you have transparent true.

Comment: Look in dev tools under network and watch where the image is being loaded. My guess is that sometimes the image doesn't fully load before you create the geometry. You could test this by trying to reset the material texture after everything loads.